# Simple.Data query by multiple values - WHERE IN ()

Tags: simple.data

Using Simple.Data how can I pass multiple values to a query?

Example generated SQL:

```
SELECT a,b,c
FROM GreatTable
WHERE x in (1,2,3)
```

Join support would be nice, too.

Does Simple.Data allow this sort of thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have no gaps in your values e.g. 1,2,3,4 then use:-

```
var list = db.GreatTable.FindAllByX(1.to(4));
```

this produces a `where x BETWEEN 1 AND 4`

Otherwise if you have gaps in your range, e.g. 1,2,4,6 then use an integer array:-

```
var list = db.GreatTable.FindAllByX(new[] { 1, 2, 4, 6 });
```

this produces a `where x IN (1,2,4,6)`

Comment: Thanks where is the second (no gaps) option documented? I couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: Sure enough. I completely overlooked it. Thanks!

Comment: No worries, glad to be of help

Comment: Link has been updated to http://simplefx.org/simpledata/docs/pages/Retrieve/WhereClauses.html